# The “SELECT…IN…” operator is not working in procedure

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure. but I am not getting expected results.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getHierarchy` (IN selectedValue LONGTEXT, IN selectedLevel VARCHAR(30))
CASE selectedLevel
 WHEN 'department' THEN 
    SELECT department_key,department,class_key,modified_class,subclass_key,modified_subclass,product_key,product_name FROM dim_product where department_key in (selectedValue) ORDER BY department_key,class_key,subclass_key,product_key;

 WHEN 'class' THEN  
    SELECT department_key,department,class_key,modified_class,subclass_key,modified_subclass,product_key,product_name FROM dim_product where class_key in (selectedValue) ORDER BY department_key,class_key,subclass_key,product_key;

 WHEN 'subclass' THEN   
    SELECT department_key,department,class_key,modified_class,subclass_key,modified_subclass,product_key,product_name FROM dim_product where subclass_key in (selectedValue) ORDER BY department_key,class_key,subclass_key,product_key;
 END CASE;
END
```

The following call is giving only 1 details :

```
call getHierarchy("1,2",'subclass');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a string variable to an `IN` predicate without resorting to dynamic SQL. Another option in MySQL (probably the easiest one in your case) would be to use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function. For instance, your "subclass" query should then be replaced by this:

```
SELECT 
    department_key, 
    department,
    class_key,
    modified_class,
    subclass_key,
    modified_subclass,
    product_key,
    product_name 
FROM dim_product 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(subclass_key, selectedValue)
ORDER BY department_key, class_key, subclass_key, product_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
call getHierarchy("1,2",'subclass');
```

to

```
call getHierarchy("'1','2'",'subclass');
```